# How to add create powershell aliases for git commands

Tags: git, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have been tired of doing `git add` & `git commit` everyday
I know in Linux you can just edit your bashrc using 1 line command
But since I use windows I am having a hard time creating an alias for

```
 Fucntion gcd {
    Insert("git commit")
}
Set-Alias gcm gcd
```

But I get an error

```
Set-Alias : Alias is not writeable because alias gcm is read-only or constant and cannot be written to.
```

I also tried without using Insert Keyword even without functions still getting an error

Comment: gcm is already a powershell alias for Get-Command, so you can't override it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to rely on your specific shell for aliases, since Git already [supports them out of the box](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

> If you don’t want to type the entire text of each of the Git commands, you can easily set up an alias for each command using `git config`.

Git aliases are defined in the `.gitconfig` file, either globally or for a particular repository.

In your case, you can create a global alias for `git commit` by saying:

```sh
git config --global alias.gcd commit
```

Comment: Thank you it really helped my Since I Posh-git is not working I don't know why

Comment: And also once i run this command I don't have to run this on every terminal session right? it will be permanent right

Comment: Yes—if you set it in Git's global `.gitconfig` file, it will be available in all sessions for the current user.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just try tu use [posh-git](https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git)

posh-git is a PowerShell module that integrates Git and PowerShell by providing Git status summary information that can be displayed in the PowerShell prompt, e.g.:

```
C:\Users\Keith\GitHub\posh-git [main ≡ +0 ~1 -0 | +0 ~1 -0 !]>
```

posh-git also provides tab completion support for common git commands, branch names, paths and more. For example, with posh-git, PowerShell can tab complete git commands like checkout by typing git ch and pressing the tab key. That will tab complete to git checkout and if you keep pressing tab, it will cycle through other command matches such as cherry and cherry-pick. You can also tab complete remote names and branch names e.g.: git pull or ma tab completes to git pull origin main.

Comment: ok but can posh-git be installed along with oh-my-posh, because I already have oh-my-posh installed on powershell...
i am saying can I have both?

Comment: Yes I've got both. on my Windows 10, Jus be carrefull how you manage your `$Profile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can create PowerShell profile that autorun when open PowerShell
First open PowerShell and create PowerShell profile (If you don't already have one):

> `New-Item -Type file -Path $PROFILE -Force`

This command will create directory in Documents call **`WindowsPowerShell`** inside this directory will create file call **`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`**

If you want to know the full path of **`Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`** write this command:

> **`$PROFILE`**

Open it from PowerShell with this command

> **`powershell_ise.exe $PROFILE`**

And write all commands that you want to alias it for example:

```bash
function gn{git init}
# @args you can pass multi arguments for example
# ga fileName1 fileName2 
function add{git add @args}
function commit { git commit -m @args }
function gac{git add .;git commit -m @args}
function gpm{git push origin master}
function pull{git pull origin master}
function gl{git log}
function glo{git log --oneline}
function gch{git checkout @args}

# @args is optional to add argument
function gb{git branch @args}
function gs{git status}
function gd{git diff}
```

Save it And close PowerShell, Open it again and call alias commands by function name for example initialize git repository write this command:

> `gn`

To add files write this commands

> `add fileName1`

See GIF image
[image: aliases git commands from PowerShell]

To show content of alias commands write this command:

> `Get-Content $PROFILE`